# How to Open console in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, console

I currently have a `console application` by using the setting illustrated in the image bellow. However Now I wish to open multiple forms with the `console` so I'm wondering if I can somehow open multiple forms or open the `console` within a `Windows Forms Application`

[image: Here is the Project's settings]

Comment: You can't open console in an "Windows Forms Application" Type.

Comment: Actually you can.  It requires extra programming but it can be done.

Comment: @tinstaafl can you share this extra programming or a link to a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> @tinstaafl can you share this extra programming or a link to a
>   solution. Thanks

Here's a couple of links:

[Console and WinForm together for easy debugging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9197/Console-and-WinForm-together-for-easy-debugging)

[Console Enhancements](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4426/Console-Enhancements)

Here's a conversion of the first one.  You'll need a form with a checkbox name "CheckBox1":

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Win32.AllocConsole()
            Console.WriteLine("Done!")
        Else
            Win32.FreeConsole()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Win32
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Public Shared Function AllocConsole() As Boolean

    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Public Shared Function FreeConsole() As Boolean

    End Function

End Class
```

Everytime you click the checkbox you show or hide the console.  You can write to and read from the same as any console app.

Comment: These links are great but is there anything for vb.net instead of c# because otherwise I will need to convert it all which could take a while. Thanks

Comment: this is great and works however is there a way to check if the console is terminated by using the console because currently if closed it stops my whole programme

Comment: It can be done but it requires more in depth programming of the Windows32 API.  If you mention more specifically what it is you want to do, there is probably a better solution than using a console.

Answer (score 1):

Forms and Console applications are very different.  So much so that generally speaking a process either needs to be a form or console application.  Forms applications are implemented with a message pump and console applications are command line drive.  It is possible to a degree to run a form within a console, and vice versa, but generally not recommended.  If you truly need both I would highly encourage you to use 2 processes.

If you could elaborate a bit more on your use case we may be better able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

So this is very cool.  In the designer just add a checkbox using the Toolbox common controls.

Then double click on the new "CheckBox1" and that will automatically insert this sub routine:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

End Sub
```

Then all you have to do is add this code:

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Win32.AllocConsole()
        Console.WriteLine("Done!")
    Else
        Win32.FreeConsole()
    End If
```

When you run your windows form program and check the box it will automatically open the window and KEEP it open until you uncheck the box.

Add this class to the bottom of your program:

```
Public Class Win32 

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Public Shared Function AllocConsole() As Boolean

    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Public Shared Function FreeConsole() As Boolean

    End Function

End Class
```

And be sure to add the Imports statement at the top

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a console window to interact with and when you close the console, that action won't terminate your windows program then you can add these two lines of code:

Dim myProcess As Process

myProcess = Process.Start("cmd.exe")